# generate a PDF file containing Persian and English characters with iText 5.5.5

Tags: android, fonts

Can somebody recommend the best way to html file to pdf file in android Project.

I'm using iText 5.5.5 to generate a PDF file containing Persian and English characters, simultaneously. So, I used the following code:

```
 private void createPDF (File file){

        //path for the PDF file to be generated
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;

        //create a new document
        Document document = new Document();

        try {

            //get Instance of the PDFWriter
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));

            //document header attributes
            document.addAuthor("betterThanZero");
            document.addCreationDate();
            document.addProducer();
            document.addCreator("MySampleCode.com");
            document.addTitle("Demo for iText XMLWorker");
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

            //open document
            document.open();

            //To convert a HTML file from the filesystem
            //String File_To_Convert = "docs/SamplePDF.html";
            //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(File_To_Convert);

            //URL for HTML page
            AssetManager am = getAssets();
            Tidy tidy=new Tidy();
            File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getPackageName() );
            if ( !path.exists() ){ path.mkdir(); }
            File filefff = new File(path, "test.xhtml");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filefff);
            tidy.parse(am.open("test.html"), fileOutputStream);



            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filefff);



            InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);

            //get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance
            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
            //convert to PDF
            worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);

            //close the document
            document.close();
            //close the writer
            pdfWriter.close();

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

output :

```
1 - Ø ̄Ù Ø³Øª Ø§ÙÙ Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û Ú ̄Ø±Ù Ú©Ø±Ø ̄Ù Ù Ø¢ÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ø³Ø§Ø²Û ÙÙØ§ØμÙ Ù
Ø¹Ø¶ÙØ§Øª Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û ÛÚ© ØªÙØ±ÛÙ Ø³ÙÚ ̄ÛÙ Ø§ÙØ¬Ø§Ù ÙÛØ ́ÙÙØ ̄Ø ÙØ ̈Ø§ÛØ ̄ Ø§Ø²
ÙØ²ÙÙ ÙØ§Û Ø³ÙÚ ̄ÛÙ Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û Ø§ÛÙ Ø ̄Ù Ø³Øª Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ú©Ø±Ø ̄.
2 - ÛÚ© Ø³Øª ÙÙ Ù¾Ø ́Øª Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù Ù¾Ø±Ø³ Ø³ÛÙÙ Ø§Û Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û Ø¢Ø ́ÙØ§ÛÛ ÙÙØ§ØμÙ
Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û ÙØ³ÛØ± Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø ̄ÙÙ Ø³ÙÙ¾Ø± Ø³Øª Ø§Ø¬Ø±Ø§ ÙÛØ ́ÙØ ̄.
3 - Ø§Ø¬Ø±Ø§Û Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø³ÛÙ Ú©Ø ́ ÙØ ̈Ù Ø§Ø² Ù¾Ø±Ø³ Ø³ÛÙÙ Ø ̄Ø³Øª Ø¬ÙØ¹Ø
Ù¾Ø ̄ÛØ ̄ Ø¢ÙØ±ÙØ ̄Ù Ø³ÛØ³ØªÙ Ù¾ÛØ ́ Ø®Ø³ØªÚ ̄Û Ø ̄Ø± Ø§ÛÙ Ø³ÙÙ¾Ø± Ø³Øª Ø§Ø³ØªØ
Ø ̈Ø ̄ÛÙ ØªØ±ØªÛØ ̈ Ú©ÙØ Ø ̄Ø± Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø§ÙÙ ÙÙØ· Ø¹Ø¶ÙÙ Ù¾Ø ́Øª Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù ÙØ¹Ø§Ù
Ø§Ø³Øª Ù Ø ̄Ø± Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø ̄ÙÙØ Ø³Ø±Ø ́Ø§ÙÙ Ù Ø³ÛÙÙ ÙÛØ² Ø ̈Ù Ú©ÙÚ© Ù¾Ø ́Øª
Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù ÙÛ Ø¢ÛÙØ ̄ Ù Ø ̈Ù ÙØ±Ø²Ø ́Ú©Ø§Ø± Ø§Ø¬Ø§Ø±Ù ÙÛØ ̄ÙÙØ ̄Ø ØªØ±Ø§ÛØ³Ù¾Ø³
Ø®ÙØ ̄ Ø±Ø§ Ø ̈ÛØ ́ Ø§Ø² Ù¾ÛØ ́ ØªØ-Øª ÙØ ́Ø§Ø± ÙØ±Ø§Ø± Ø ̄ÙØ ̄.
Ø§Ø²Ø·Ø±ÙÛ Ø§Ø¬Ø±Ø§Û Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø§ÙÙ Ø ̈Ø§ Ø³ÛØ³ØªÙ Ú©ÙØªØ±Ù Ù ØªÙØ±Ú©Ø²
ØμÙØ±Øª ÙÛÚ ̄ÛØ±Ø ̄Ø ÛØ¹ÙÛ ÙØ±Ø²Ø ́Ú©Ø§Ø± Ø§Ø ̈ØªØ ̄Ø§ Ø ̄Ù ØªÚ©Ø±Ø§Ø± Ù¾Ø ́Øª
Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù Ø³ÛÙ Ú©Ø ́ Ø±Ø§ Ø ̈Ø§ Ú©ÙØªØ±Ù Ú©Ø§ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ¬Ø§Ù Ø ̄Ø§Ø ̄Ù Ù Ø³Ù¾Ø³
Ø ̈Ø ̄ÙÙ ÙÚ©Ø« Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ù¾Ø ́Øª Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù Ù¾Ø±Ø³ Ø³ÛÙÙ Ø±Ø§ Ø ̄Ø± Ø ̄Ù
ØªÚ©Ø±Ø§Ø± Ø ̄ÛÚ ̄Ø± Ø ̄ÙØ ̈Ø§Ù ÙÛÚ©ÙØ ̄. Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û ÚØ§Ø ́ÙÛ Ú©Ø§Ø± ÙÛØªÙØ§Ù
Ø ̄Ù ØªÚ©Ø±Ø§Ø± Ú©ÙÚ©Û Ø ̄ÛÚ ̄Ø± ÙÛØ² Ø ̄Ø± Ø§ÛÙ Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ø§Ø®ÛØ± Ø§Ø¬Ø±Ø§
Ú©Ø±Ø ̄.
Ø ̄Ù Ø³Øª Ø ̈Ø§ Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ø§Ø² Ø§ÛÙ Ú©ÙÚ©Ø³ÛÙÙ Ø³ÛØ³ØªÙ ÙØ§Û Ø-Ø±ÙÙ Ø§Û
Ø ̄Ø± Ø§ÛÙ Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª Ú©Ø§ÙÛ Ø§Ø³ØªØ ØªØ§ ØªØ±Ø§ÛØ³Ù¾Ø³ ÚØ§Ø±Ù Ø§Û Ø¬Ø²
Ø±Ø ́Ø ̄ Ú©Ø±Ø ̄Ù ÙØ ̄Ø§Ø ́ØªÙ Ø ̈Ø§Ø ́Ø ̄.
4 - Ø ̄Ø± Ø§ÛÙ Ø ̄Ù Ø³ÙÙ¾Ø± Ø³Øª ÙÛØ² ÙØ¬ÙØ ̄ Ù¾Ø ́Øª Ø ̈Ø§Ø²Ù ÙØ§ÙØªØ±
Ø®ÙØ§Ø ̈ÛØ ̄Ù ÙØ ̈Ù Ø§Ø² Ù¾Ø§Ø±Ø§ÙÙ Ø³Ø ̈Ø ̈ Ø§ÛØ¬Ø§Ø ̄ Ø³ÛØ³ØªÙ Ù¾ÛØ ́
Ø®Ø³ØªÚ ̄Û ÙÛØ ́ÙØ ̄. Ø ̄ÙØª Ø ̈Ù ÙØ§ØμÙÙ Ø§Ø³ØªØ§ÙØ ̄Ø§Ø±Ø ̄ Ø ̄Ø³ØªÙØ§ Ø ̄Ø±
Ø-Ø±Ú©Øª ÙØ§ÙØªØ± Ø®ÙØ§Ø ̈ÛØ ̄Ù Ø§Ø² Ø§ÙÙÛØª Ø²ÛØ§Ø ̄Û Ø ̈Ø±Ø®ÙØ±Ø ̄Ø§Ø±
Ø§Ø³ØªØ ÚÙÙ Ú©Ù Ø ̈ÙØ ̄Ù Ø§ÛÙ ÙØ§ØμÙÙ ÙÛØªÙØ§ÙØ ̄ ÙÙØ¬Ø± Ø ̈Ù Ø ̄Ø±Ø ̄ÙØ§Û
Ø ́Ø ̄ÛØ ̄ Ø ̄Ø± ÙÙØμÙ ÙÚ Ù Ø¢Ø³ÛØ ̈ Ø ̄ÛØ ̄Ú ̄Û Ø¢Ù Ø ́ÙØ ̄. Ø ̈Ø¹Ø ̄ Ø§Ø² Ø ̄Ù
ØªÚ©Ø±Ø§Ø±Ø ÙØ±Ø²Ø ́Ú©Ø§Ø± Ø ̈Ù Ø³Ø±Ø¹Øª Ø³Ø±Ø§Øº Ù¾Ø§Ø±Ø§ÙÙ Ø±ÙØªÙ Ù Ø ̄Ù
ØªÚ©Ø±Ø§Ø± Ø ̄ÛÚ ̄Ø± ÙÛØ² Ø ̄Ø± Ø§ÛÙØ¬Ø§ Ø§ÙØ¬Ø§Ù ÙÛØ ̄ÙØ ̄. Ø ̄Ù Ø³Øª Ø§ÙÙ
Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û Ú ̄Ø±Ù Ú©Ø±Ø ̄Ù Ù Ø¢ÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ø³Ø§Ø²Û ÙÙØ§ØμÙ Ø§Ø³Øª Ù
Ø ̄Ø±ØμÙØ±ØªÛÚ©Ù ÙØ ̄Ø±Øª Ø ̈Ø ̄ÙÛ Ø§Ø¬Ø§Ø²Ù Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ø§Ø² ÙØ²ÙÙ ÙØ§Û
Ø ̈ÛØ ́ØªØ±Û Ø±Ø§ ÙÛØ ̄ÙØ ̄Ø ÙÛØªÙØ§Ù Ø§Ø² ÙØ²ÙÙ Ø§Ø¶Ø§ÙÛ Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø ̄Ù
Ú©Ø±Ø ̄. Ø ̈Ø±Ø§Û Ø§ÛÙ Ú©Ø§Ø± Ø ̈Ø§ ÙÙØ§Ø ̈ Ú©Ø±Ø ̄Ù Ù¾Ø§ÙØ§ Ø ̄Ø± ÛÚ©Ø ̄ÛÚ ̄Ø±
ÛÚ© Ø ̄ÙØ ̈Ù Ø±Ø§ Ø ̄Ø± ÙÛØ§Ù Ø¢ÙÙØ§ ÙØ±Ø§Ø± Ø ̄Ø§Ø ̄Ù ÛØ§ ÙÛØªÙØ§Ù Ø§Ø²
Ú©ÙØ±Ø ̈ÙØ ̄ ÙØ®ØμÙØμ ÙØ²ÙÙ Ø§Ø¶Ø§ÙÛ Ø§Ø³ØªÙØ§Ø ̄Ù Ú©Ø±Ø ̄.
ÙØ±Ø¬Ø¹ : Ú©ØªØ§Ø ̈ Ø-Ø±ÙÙ Ø§Û Ø ̈Ø§Ø ́
```

Where is the problem? how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Pdfwriter to write file in gujarati language. To write in language other than English we need to create Basefont as shown in the code below:

```
Font font=null;
try {
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("assets/xxx.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);                   
    font = new Font(bf, 12);
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("ListActivity","fontException"+e);
}
```

Note: Save .ttf file of persian language in asset folder. Replace xxx.ttf with your ttf file name.
Then, pass this font while writing into the pdf file. Like in my case I did:

```
table.addCell((new PdfPCell(new Phrase(user.getSurname(),font))));
table.addCell((new PdfPCell(new Phrase(user.getName(),font))));
```

Hope you can relate to this and the answer is helpful.